# Can Miles Edgeworth submit an updated autopsy?

Tags: phoenix-wright

In "Turnabout Sisters", Miles Edgeworth provides a second autopsy that puts the case more in his favor. Assuming this is an actual case that followed actual laws and procedures of Japan, would he actually be able to produce such a thing legally?

Comment: @F1Krazy Duelling edits, but that's a balalaika, not a banjo.

Comment: Given that the game is fantasy, asking whether an element of it is the same as reality seems relatively on-topic. **Objection overruled!**